# Advanced Installer for VB6 project is detected by anti virus software

Tags: vb6, exe, antivirus, advanced-installer

I have created a `VB6` project and also created installer for this project using `Advanced Installer`, my Anti Virus (`Norton`) immediately deletes installer file and it and says that it's a virus.

So my question is, is there any solution to this problem? Why is my project detected as a virus?

Comment: Are you using a DLL?

Comment: not using any DLL

Comment: Do you know for certain that your installer does not contain a virus?

Comment: Are you building your installer as an exe or an msi?

Comment: @BrianMStafford I am build as an exe

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your why question precisely, but it comes down to the combination of your application files and the configuration of your installer project.  On the Advanced Installer support website it has been reported that the following configuration can cause false positives with anti-virus software:

- using the "Enhanced User Interface" feature
- using the "Single EXE setup (resources inside)" package type

So what is the solution?  You can try the following:

- build your installer as an msi
- build your installer as an "EXE setup with resources next to it"

Comment: I cannot able to build a installer as msi if my advanced installer project have pre-install prerequisites.. In this case, how can I avoid anti-virus problem?